# Installing Traefik using ArgoCD : values.yaml not loaded

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, traefik, argocd

I'm trying to deploy Traefik using ArgoCD.

The application is properly loaded but it doesn't load my values file.

Chart.yaml

```
apiVersion: v2
name: traefik
type: application
version: 1.0.0
appVersion: "1.0.0"
dependencies:
- name: traefik
  version: 26.0.0
  repository: https://traefik.github.io/charts
```

values.yaml

```
traefik:
  additionalArguments:
    - --serversTransport.insecureSkipVerify=true
    - --providers.kubernetescrd.allowCrossNamespace=true
    - --certificatesresolvers.letsencrypt.acme.tlschallenge=true
    - --certificatesresolvers.letsencrypt.acme.email=john@doe.com
    - --certificatesresolvers.letsencrypt.acme.storage=/data/acme.json
```

I'm using this command to deploy :

```
argocd app create traefik --project services --repo git@host/repo.git --path traefik --dest-server https://kubernetes.default.svc --dest-namespace traefik --sync-option CreateNamespace=true --sync-policy automated
```

Comment: you should look into https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-guide/multiple_sources/#helm-value-files-from-external-git-repository

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your issue, but in my case, the setup worked fine.

Let me explain to you exactly what I did.

1. Create a git repository (e.g. `git@host/repo.git`) with the following structure:

```
.
└── traefik
    ├── Chart.yaml
    └── values.yaml
```

The content of both files is exactly like yours.

2. Create an Argo Project in my cluster, called `services`

```
argocd proj create services --dest https://kubernetes.default.svc,traefik

argocd proj add-source services git@host/repo.git
```

3. Create an Argo App

```
argocd app create traefik --project services --repo git@host/repo.git --path traefik --dest-server https://kubernetes.default.svc --dest-namespace traefik --sync-option CreateNamespace=true --sync-policy automated
```

I hope this helps!